# How do I solve a knapsack problem with negative items that have to go into if they physically can?

Tags: algorithm, knapsack-problem

I have a problem with program that is similar to backpack but has two little differences.

First value of items can be negative.

Second if there is room for item in the backpack it HAS TO even if it lowers packback's current value.

The common aproach doesn't help because if my items are

```
Weigh Value

1 100

2 1

1 -1000
```

And backpack has the capacity of 2 and each item can go into the backpack once

First item will insert

```
0 to backpack of 0

100 to backpack of 1 

100 to backpack of 2
```

So far so good but second item will never go in as its value is lower then first one and third ruins everything because backpack of 1 will be the same but this horrible item fits in the backpack of 2 and value lowers to -900 since I can't skip it when I could just be fine with the second item and have the value of 1.

The point is to insert the items that seem worse but take more room so the worst items can't go in.

Unfortunately if items were following:

```
Weigh Value

1 100

2 1

1 -10
```

then backpack with first and third item is better than backpack with second so I can't brainlessly fill my backpack with whatever positive valued items to deny the negative ones cause it's sometimes (example above) not the answer.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: *but this approach doesn't work for some reason*: ?? Could you provide more information on this statement, for example through an example

Comment: @Nick893 - Your assertions seem arbitrary, since you don't specify the underlying algorithm. So, what shall be discussed?

Comment: As you HAVE TO put items then the problem can be reduced to: new_capacity = original_capacity+sum(abs(negatively_weighted_items). Now place positively weighted items as usual. (But what does it means HAVE TO with positive weights??? This point is not clear).

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Items can't have negative weighs, just values :) The point is so recognise when fill the backpack to deny the negative items or when to let them in bcs our positive items are better. "have to" means i can't choose not to put negative item in if there is room for it, but i can choose another to deny it.